# DB connection string fails to connect to database when the password has Equal to Sign (i.e = ) in the password value

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

The connection to the database fails when it has equal to sign in the password value of the connection string. What am I missing in the code below that my connection string fails? Do I have to do anything else for this? As rest all the passwords work just the one with Equal To sign fails.

```
CString ADOPage::BuildConnectionString(const CString &Database)
{
    CString FormatString(_T("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=%s;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=%s;Initial Catalog=%s;Data Source=%s"));
    CString returnString;
    returnString.Format(FormatString.GetBuffer(0), m_ADO_PrivPassword, m_ADO_PrivUser, Database, m_ADO_SQLServer);

    return returnString;
}
```

**m_ADO_PrivPassword** this has the password value coming from the user and for testing purpose I was using the below mentioned as the passwords.

Test=one2#`\

Testone2#`==

Comment: According to MSFT you should either escape the = (by adding a second equals), or surrounding it in {} brackets, depending on whether you'r ODBC or OLE. Its worth trying both of those.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-odbcstr/c4daeacc-aea1-40ca-a35b-2567edef8b8b and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-oledbstr/cfc4c822-49bc-4095-844d-4421b8655ecb

Comment: @MikeVine I did try adding a second equal (=) sign and including it in the curly braces {} but It didn't work for me.